# How to clip ITN Network Dataset in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I have an Integrated Transport Network dataset that I downloaded from Edina Digimap that I was planning on using for Service Area and Closest Facility analysis in ArcGIS 10.2.2.

I have downloaded, converted and prepared the data for use in ArcGIS following [these instructions](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~gisteac/resources/Using%20OS%20MasterMap%20ITN%20with%20ArcGIS%20v%202.0.pdf) and the data loads up and can be used for routing *etc*.

However, I need to clip the ITN Network Dataset so it matches a county boundary that I have as a shapefile so as to restrict routing to within the county only.

[image: This is the full ITN Network Dataset downloaded from Digimap. I need to clip it to match the NorfolkCountyOutline in blue]

The Clip tool won't let me Clip the Network Dataset that was built from the ITN files. I can Clip the individual files themselves (...) but what do I do with the newly clippped shapefiles?

**How do I combine the clipped shapefiles to build a new clipped Network Dataset? Or is there a better way to create a clipped network dataset?**

[image]

I'm lost!

Comment: I don't use ArcGIS so can't help you with that, but I do use ITN, and I often clip it. I do it in Postgres/Postgis. Is that something you can/do use?

Comment: @JohnBarça I have no experience with Postgres/Postgis yet. I was planning to use them, but needed to get this done quickly and thought Arc would be the quicker option. Not so it seems. I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating shapefiles with the clipping operation? All you should need to do is clip the feature classes in the gdb, in place (making a copy of the data first is always a good idea), and then rebuild the network (right-click on it). If you clip everything to shapefiles you pretty much have to start from scratch to rebuild a whole new network - importing the data to a gdb and feature dataset, setting up a new network dataset and pointing/adding/configuring all the different layers and restrictions, etc.

Comment: Select by location save to your file geodtabase rebuild the network will give your Norfolk county ready for Service Areas http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002q000000 Note: ArcGIS is slow with ITN data.

Comment: @ChrisW Not really sure why I was creating shapefiles! I tried clipping the individual feature classes, then rebuilding the clipped network and it worked! I now have an ITN network that fits my county and works with routing! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clip won't work on the Network Dataset itself, but it should work on all the component feature classes that go into the dataset. Rather than clipping to a shapefile (which basically gives you all new features to start building a whole new network from the ground up), just clip/modify the existing feature classes in the gdb (making a copy first of course). As Mapperz suggests, you can also use select by locations rather than clip - there are probably a few ways to reduce the dataset.

If you have issues overwriting existing feature classes/same names, you can write to a temporary (say, 'original_clip'), delete the original, and rename the modified one. That way you don't have to point at a bunch of new names/fix links.

Once you've updated all the component feature classes, you just need to rebuild the network by right-clicking on it in Catalog. This will preserve all the configuration that went into setting up the network itself, and just update the geometry in it.